# Build 64-bit R Package with Rtools and External Library / DLL

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm building/installing an R package on Windows created with Rcpp skeleton. For a while I was just building a 32-bit version that links a 32-bit dll. My Makevars file looked like this:

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I"D:/projects/source/my_project"
PKG_LIBS = -L"D:/projects/source/my_project/Release" -lproject
```

and I would run

```
R CMD build Package
R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch --no-test-load --build Package_1.0.tar.gz
```

In a cmd prompt and all would be fine. Now I need the 64-bit version also. I made my Makevars look like this:

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I"D:/projects/source/my_project"
PKG_LIBS = -L"D:/projects/source/my_project/Release" -lproject -lprojectx64
```

Where my 64 bit dll is named projectx64.dll. The issue is when I run the command:

```
R CMD INSTALL --build Package_1.0.tar.gz
```

The build fails because during the 32-bit build process because the compiler tries to link the 64 bit dll. What is a way around this to get it to sequentially link the dll's for the appropriate architecture?

As a P.S. I've read the big red text that says "NO WINDOWS!" in the Rcpp manual but that is simply inaccurate and I don't see how my issue would be different on Linux.

### EDIT

Here is the output of the INSTALL command. It predicatbly fails when 32-bit gcc is launched and tries to link in the 64-bit dll specficied in the Makevars.

```
*** arch - i386
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/R/R-3.3.1/include" -DNDEBUG -    I"D:/projects/source/my_project"   -I"C:/Users/rk/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/Rcpp/include" -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/R/R-3.3.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I"D:/projects/source/my_project"   -I"C:/Users/rk/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/Rcpp/include" -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c cstyle.cpp -o cstyle.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o Package.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o cstyle.o -LD:/projects/source/my_project/Release -lproject -lprojectx64 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/i386 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/R/R-3.3.1/bin/i386 -lR
D:/projects/source/my_project/Release/projectx64.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Package'
* removing 'C:/Users/rk/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/Package'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/rk/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/Package'
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand.  By default _each_ build on Windows is 32 _and_ 64 bit.  Just try on [win-builder](http://win-builder.r-project.org).

Comment: Also, this: `"D:/projects/source/my_project"` is not ideal as the package is then bound to your machine since it is an absolute path instead of a relative path.

Comment: R CMD check fails with same message. I understand it uses both architectures by default but then how can one link the proper architecture's library file? Running R CMD INSTALL launches 32 bit gcc for the 32 bit build and fails (obviously) when it tries to link in the 64 bit library.

Comment: Use `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` to create a working source package.  Build it.  Verify that it works in 32 bit _and_ 64 bit.  We do not know what you do after that step, but you appear to be doing something non-standard which breaks things.  There are almost 900 packages on CRAN using Rcpp, and they all build just fine in both 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I'm not being clear. My issue is my package uses an external library file. When I go to install the package I cannot figure out how to get only the 32-bit external library to link during 32-bit package installation and 64 to 64 for the second build.

Comment: Including external libraries is hard. I don't know anything about `lproject`, but FWIW I also tried to include a C library with Rcpp one time, and was only able to compile on 32-bit Windows. For guidance you should look at the Makevars for some other Rcpp packages that include external libraries.

Comment: And/or condition your package build on just one sub-architecture.  This has nothing to do with Rcpp _per se_ but is all about (more advanced) package building on Windows.  Which is documented too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took Dirk's advice and built two separate packages for each architecture. Makevars of course only links in the appropriate library for each build. The choice of architecture used when running the `--no_multiarch` flag is determined by whichever R version is set first in your `PATH`. The version can be seen by running `R --version` in a command prompt. Change your `PATH` for each build.

I'll add that you have to add a manifest on Windows to get this to work. Add this to a stdafx.h file in a Visual Studio Project:

```
#if defined _M_IX86
  #pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_IA64
  #pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='ia64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_X64
  #pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#else
  #pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#endif
```

This is because there's a super cool bug in Window's LoadLibrary function (that has been present for years without fix) used by R to load DLLs that will try to call a 32bit Common Controls DLL in calling your 64-bit DLL causing the entire load to fail.

Comment: Saying "I took Dirk's advice and built two separate packages for each architecture." misunderstands, and even misrepresents, what I said.

Comment: Here is a [src/Makefile.win](https://github.com/Rblp/Rblpapi/blob/master/src/Makevars.win) (from a project I am a co-author of) that is appropriately detecting 32 and 64 bit when dealing with an external library.